# fill factor of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I am new to SQL Server 2008 fill factor, as mentioned here in SQL Server 2008 BOL,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx

My 2 confusions,

1. Whether fill factor applies to index page? Or applies to both index and data page? At the beginning, seems fill factor applies only to index page -- "The fill-factor option is provided for fine-tuning index data storage and performance", but at the end it is mentioned -- "If existing rows will be updated with data that lengthens the size of the rows, use a fill factor of less than 100. The extra bytes on each page will help to minimize page splits caused by extra length in the rows.". Any comments?
2. Whether fill factor takes effect to only rebuild index/create index operation (only rebuild/create index will utilize free space reserved by fill factor), or applies to any insert/update operation (any insert/update operation will utilize free space reserved by fill factor)?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FILLFACTOR applies to index pages only.  But the catch here is that if you have a clustered index (and most tables do), your FILLFACTOR will essentially apply to your data as well, since your data lives inside the leaf-nodes of your clustered index.  Basically, if you have a truly read-only table, set the FILLFACTOR to 100 for all of its indexes.  That will get you the smallest and fastest table possible for any given index structure.  Be aware that if you set FILLFACTOR to 100 for indexes on data which will be modified, you're setting yourself up for page splitting and possibly degraded performance.

A FILLFACTOR which is set too high can affect performance on insert/update operations.  You will get page splits when you modify enough data.  This is part of the intrinsic nature of the [B-tree index structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) -- it automatically balances the tree.  If you want to adjust the FILLFACTOR to an explicit setting, [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) says that this only takes effect when you rebuild the index.

Comment: Thanks Dave, 1. "this only takes effect when you rebuild the index." -- you mean the new fill factor setting (suppose I change the value of fill factor explicitly) only takes effect when we rebuild index? 2. update operation will utilize load factor because the index value in B-Tree of the updated column may change, and may be moved from one index page to another index page (so if the destination index page reserved space, it will not do page split)?

Comment: Yes.  If you set the FILLFACTOR on an index with ALTER INDEX, you will need to rebuild it in order for your new setting to take effect.

An UPDATE can definitely cause a page split in the scenario you describe.

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry a stupid question, alter index will always cause index rebuild? so heavy operation.

Comment: George -- no, I don't believe it does.  There is an ALTER INDEX REBUILD statement which will do both, though, I believe.

Comment: Sorry my bad English, I think when you mentioned "set the FILLFACTOR on an index with ALTER INDEX", you mean using statement like this <rebuild_index_option > ::= FILLFACTOR = fillfactor? (previous I mis-understand that you mean alter index will trigger index rebuild, and will finally applies new fill factor value because of index rebuild.)

Answer (score 0):

Fill factor give information about..how much space available in a SQL page which is default 8kb.For Example..
Suppose FF=20% that means 100-20=80 % of space is filled.The default value of the Fill Factor is 100, 100-100=0% space filled